# Convergence in distribution of $\sqrt{n-3}(z -\zeta)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, asymptotics

Let $(x_i,y_i)$ be iid $(x,y), i = 1,..,n$ be any bivariate sample. The correlation coefficient
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\rho & = \text{cor}(x,y) \\
 & = \frac{\text{cov}(x,y)}{\sqrt{\text{var}(x)} \sqrt{\text{var}(y)}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
is usually estimated by the sample correlation coefficient
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
r & = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{|\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2|^\frac{1}{2} |\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2|^\frac{1}{2}}\\
 & = \frac{(\textbf{x} - \bar{x}\textbf{1})^{\text{T}}(\textbf{y} - \bar{y}\textbf{1})}{ |\textbf{x} - \bar{x}\textbf{1}||\textbf{y} - \bar{y}\textbf{1}|}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now,
\begin{align*} 
z &= \frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1+r}{1-r})   \\ 
\zeta &= \frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho})
\end{align*}
How to show that $\sqrt{n-3}(z -\zeta)$ converges in distribution $N(0,1)$?
I dont know how to invoke CLT here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shall we presume "$p$" is a synonym for "$\rho$"?

Comment: @whuber yup. I just typed it incorrectly. I already edited my post.

Comment: You could use [Fisher z transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation) as keyword. The result does not seem to be an application of the Central Limit Theorem but rather a skillfull derivation starting from an expression of the true density (as given by R.A. Fisher).

Comment: @Yves Yeah. You are right.